# UITableView, reloadData reload the cell but does not resize the table

Tags: iphone, uitableview, reloaddata

I have this strange behavior, when I update my dataSource ofr my UITableView and call the reloadData thing, the cells are updated but the size of the table dosen't change.

I really do not have any clue... can some one help?

Comment: if you are not getting the resolution, maybe adding some code would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

the problem usually lies in `numberOfRowsInSection`, make sure that you are recalculating the table size correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should double check both `numberOfRowsInsection` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, does your UITableViewCell has a different height than the default one, 44.f?

If it is a custom UITableViewCell, double check in nib (if you are using nib) or in your code again

Comment: Did the check, and it is OK, My cell are 80.0f in the nib files... but still... not resizing correctly :(